# Template specialization of inherited member function

Tags: c++, templates

We would like to specialize member functions of a base class. However, it does not compile. Does anybody know of any alternative that does compile?

Here is an example

```
struct Base
{
    template<typename T>
    void Foo()
    {
        throw "Foo() is not defined for this type";
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    template<>
    void Foo<int>() { cout << "Foo<int>()" << endl; } // compile error (cannot specialize members from a base class)

    template<>
    void Foo<double>() { cout << "Foo<double>()" << endl; }  // compile error (cannot specialize members from a base class)
};
```

Comment: There will be no polymorphic behaviour back to Base and you can't make the template function virtual.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: We are trying to create factory classes that have specialized members, and we want to throw an exception when we do not know how to handle the types for which the method was not specialized.

We wish to create many classes like Derived in our example. Otherwise, we wouldn't have had the Base class.

Comment: It is better to fail at compile time than throw an exception at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, we solved it using overloading.

Here is how the base class looks like

```
struct Base
{
    template<typename T>
    class OfType {}

    template<typename T>
    void Foo(OfType<T>) { static_assert(false, "Foo is not implemented for this type. Please look in the compiler error for more details."); }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    using Base::Foo;

    void Foo(OfType<int>) { // here comes logic for ints }
    void Foo(OfType<double>) { // here comes logic for doubles }
};
```

Here is an example of client code that uses `Foo()`

```
template<typename S>
class ClassThatUsesFoo
{
    private: S s;

    template<typename T>
    void Bar(T item) 
    {  
        s.Foo(Base::OfType<T>());  // this is the code that uses Foo
        DoSomeStuffWithItem(item); 
    } 
};

void main()
{
    ClassThatUsesFoo<Derived> baz;
    baz.Bar(12); // this will internally use Foo for ints
    baz.Bar(12.0); // this will use Foo for doubles
    baz.Bar("hello world"); // this will give a verbose compile error
}
```

Comment: but why do you want it to throw? Better if it is just doesn't compile.

Comment: You are correct. I will change it to a static assert, or remove it altogether. 

Anyway, the overloading allows me to create a hierarchy of Derived classes. Something that specialization does not allow me to do.

Comment: By the way a compiler error is better than a link error it will tell you where in the code you are using the bad overload, and not simply that it doesn't exist (which you know).

A couple of other points, main returns int not void, and when you throw exceptions, throw ones derived from std::exception.

Comment: You can't use polymorphism to call the specialized methods from the base, so what is the point?

Answer (score 0):

This will compile, except for the call to `Foo<char>()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    template<typename T>
    void Foo()
    {
        throw "Foo() is not defined for this type";
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    template<typename T> void Foo();
};

template<>
void Derived::Foo<int>() { cout << "Foo<int>()" << endl; }

template<>
void Derived::Foo<double>() { cout << "Foo<double>()" << endl; }

int main()
{
    Derived derived;

    // this is client code
    derived.Foo<int>(); 
    derived.Foo<double>(); 
    derived.Foo<char>();   // this throws
}
```

If you want  the call to `Foo<char>()` -- or any type not specifically specialized by you -- then this works.  If you want a non-specialized implementation that works for all types, then you need to add a non-specialized implementation of `Foo()` as well:

```
template<typename T> 
void Derived::Foo() { cout << "generic" << endl; }
```

Comment: The derived.Foo<char> does not throw. It just does not compile (link error). In addition, we will not be able to extend the Derived class with DerivedMore that contains more specializations.

Any other ideas?

Comment: @Alex: You could simply add a default implementation for `Derived::Foo`: `return Base::Foo<T>();`

Comment: @DyP: We could, but it means we will have to add it in every Derived type. What happens if I have many of those?

Comment: @Alex: I don't quite understand. If your derived classed have specialized factory methods, you already have the `Foo` function in every Derived type. If a derived type doesn't add specializations, you don't even have to provide a `Foo` method (it's inherited from the Base class).

Comment: @DyP: That's what I would like to have. But as I said can see, the sample above does not compile. In order to compile we need to re-implement the default Foo in every derived type.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the discussion with Alex (see comments of the answer of John Dibling), this is what I meant (SSCCE):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    template<typename T>
    void Foo()
    {
        //static_assert(false, "Foo() is not defined for this type");
        throw "Foo() is not defined for this type";
    }
};
    // you can add as many specializations in Base as you like
    template <>
    void Base::Foo<char>()  {  cout << "Base::Foo<char>()" << endl;  }


struct Derived : public Base
{
    // just provide a default implementation of Derived::Foo
    // that redirects the call to the hidden Base::Foo
    template < typename T >
    void Foo()
    {  Base::Foo<T>();  }
};
    // the specializations for Derived
    template<>
    void Derived::Foo<int>() { cout << "Foo<int>()" << endl; }

    template<>
    void Derived::Foo<double>() { cout << "Foo<double>()" << endl; }


struct Derived_wo_specialization : public Base
{
    /* nothing */
};


int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.Foo<char>();
    d.Foo<double>();

    Derived_wo_specialization dws;
    dws.Foo<char>();
    dws.Foo<double>();
}
```